# How make gunicorn and flask not consume huge memory

Tags: python

I use flask and gunicorn for deploy on production scale machine learning models, but the memory using gunicorn with 4 workers is very huge (almost 4x) without gunicorn. Can gunicorn use less memory?

Comment: Are you saying that gunicorn is taking 4 times the memory of the development server? If so, that's pretty much to be expected - each worker is a separate process, so it's as if you're running 4 dev servers at the same time.

Comment: I try again using 2 workers, before start the programs my RAM about 4.2GB, after try with 2 workers it consume 2.8GB (run with 1 worker it just consume 1.4GB). Sorry I cannot reproduce on 4 workers because my program going larger than before.

So using gunicorn on 2 workers is like running 2 programs at the same time?

Comment: Effectively, yes, gunicorn is just running multiple versions of the flask app, and sharing the workload between them. You might want to look into why your app is using so much memory in the first place - that looks really heavy to me.

Comment: Oh yes thanks, so nothing wrong with my apps. Thank you

Comment: I would argue that taking 1.4GB for a webapp itself is something wrong. That's a completely  unreasonable amount of memory usage, and something it's worth profiling and working to fix. If your memory usage is reasonable for a single instance (where "reasonable" is typically in tens of MB at the very most), then having gunicorn run lots of instances isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your worker to **(2*CPU)+1**. This is the suggested maximum concurrent requests when using workers and threads.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but what about RAM? Because my RAM almost full

Comment: It's normal for your RAM usage to increase since Gunicorn runs multiple instances of your app with workers. You can either optimize your Flask app to use less memory or try manipulating the `--max-requests INT`. This will limit the number of requests a work will process before automatically restarting. Also try out more options with [gunicorn settings](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html)

Comment: Oke I see, thank you very much for your help, will try soon

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, once RAM is allocated, it is not released by gunicorn. So, there may be some requests for which more memory is needed. At that time, more memory is allocated for gunicorn and it will keep using it, even if the requirement is much lower. `--max-requests` option is useful in this case.

```
gunicorn -D -w 8  --max-requests 50000 --bind 127.0.0.1:8080 myproject.wsgi:application
```

in above example, the gunicorn worker is restarted for every 50000 requests. This will cause releasing any excess memory held by gunicorn. Also adjust the worker count (`-w 8`) to `2* cpu_core + 1`